# Building an APK for android from a Python/Kivy source code

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am on trying to move a python/kivy app from a virtual machine to android device. Here is what I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git 
cd buildozer
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

to get buidozer. Then change the project directory from the shared folder to code/kivy/examples/demo and then type `buildozer init` to get buildozer spec and finally type `buildozer android debug deploy run` to build the apk.
I got the following error message:

```
Run prebuild
Call prebuild_hostpython
Call prebuild_python
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -urN Python-2.7.2/configure ltib/rpm/BUILD/Python-2.7.2/configure
|--- Python-2.7.2/configure 2011-06-11 11:46:28.000000000 -0400
|+++ ltib/rpm/BUILD/Python-2.7.2/configure  2011-11-14 12:10:41.011373524 -0500
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 25
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -urN Python-2.7.2/Makefile.pre.in ltib/rpm/BUILD/Python-2.7.2/Makefile.pre.in
|--- Python-2.7.2/Makefile.pre.in   2011-06-11 11:46:26.000000000 -0400
|+++ ltib/rpm/BUILD/Python-2.7.2/Makefile.pre.in    2011-11-14 12:10:41.013373444 -0500
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
6 out of 6 hunks ignored
patching file setup.py
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
6 out of 6 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "myapp"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: dont skip the patch say y and here is a link for above https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCWC4kWOoiI

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue run this command `buildozer android clean`
and then rebuild it using `buildozer android debug` or automatically run using `buildozer android debug deploy run`.

And also [this link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131480) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've just made a new ios/apk package. *It* is persisent with buildozer... All you need to do though is

```
buildozer android update
buildozer android release
```